# Proof of the Envelope theorem for parametric functions in the Cartesian Plane

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Given a family of parametric functions in the Cartesian Plane $(f(t,k);g(t,k))$,  their envelope is found by solving the equation:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\frac{\partial g}{\partial k}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial k}\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=0$.
How do I prove the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you should **never** use the letter $k$ for a continuous variable.

The condition you give concerns the Jacobian $J_\Phi$ of the map
$$\Phi:\quad(t,c)\mapsto\bigl(f(t,c),g(t,c)\bigr)\ .$$
If $J_\Phi(t_0,c_0)\ne0$ the map $\Phi$ maps a window with center $(t_0,c_0)$  diffeomorphically onto a neighborhood of $\bigl(f(t_0,c_0),g(t_0,c_0)\bigr)$, and this implies that the family of arcs
$$\gamma_c:\quad t\mapsto\bigl(f(t,c),g(t,c)\bigr)\qquad(t_0-h<t<t_0+h)$$
with $c_0-\delta<c<c_0+\delta$ looks like a family of parallel segments. It follows that the point $p_0:=\bigl(f(t_0,c_0),g(t_0,c_0)\bigr)$ cannot belong to the envelope of the given family of curves. Therefore your condition is *necessary* for envelope points. Sufficiency is another matter.

Comment: Thank you for the warning and for your explanation. I would like to know more about this, do you know any pdf I can download about this subject?